# Principles of a packet sniffer

Tags: c, winapi, proxy, network-programming, tcp

I'm wondering about the principles of a packet sniffer. how do they catch the packets of other application?

I have been thinking about this so long. And i got one theory. Is that related to the workings of a proxy server? When some special API is once used, all the local applications send their packets to the specified ip instead of their original. And the packet sniffer receives and copys, and finally sends them back to the original destination. Is that right?

Can you explain how a packet sniffer works?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Most packet sniffers are written using Pcap library (LibPcap or WinPcap). You can search in Codeproject.com for tutorials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Network interfaces (i.e. hardware network adapter cards) receive all traffic on the wire irrespective of whether it is addressed to them or not.

After receiving a frame, the driver checks the recipient's [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) in the [frame header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame#Structure) and compares it to the MAC of the interface. If the addresses match then the frame is forwarded to the OS for consumption; if not, it is discarded.

Interfaces also provide the option of being put into *[promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode)*, in which *all* frames are forwarded to the OS. That is what packet sniffers do: they send a command to the driver that puts the card in promiscuous mode, and can then read all traffic that physically arrives from the network no matter who it is addressed to.

Of course promiscuous mode is not a guarantee that you will receive *all* traffic on the network; network topology can easily prevent traffic addressed to others from ever reaching your system in the first place (e.g. [that's what switches typically do](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch#Layer_1_.28Hubs_versus_higher-layer_switches.29)).